# Reading Data in Columns Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-2.7, scipy

I have a data file, which I need to read. I know to read files in Python you have to do something like:

```
file = open(fileLocaion, 'r+')
```

But I do not know who to do special reads. The data I have is in columns. So `x` values in one column and `y` values in another with headers at the top. The data (my text file `a.txt`) looks like

```
 Charge (1x), Ch A, Run #1
 Time ( s ) Charge (1x) ( µC )
 0.0000 0.021
 0.1000 0.021
 0.2000 0.021
 0.3000 0.021
 0.4000 0.021
 0.5000 0.021
 0.6000 0.021
```

So the first time value is `0.0000` and the first charge value is `0.021`. I want to be able to take this into Python and use `matplotlib` to plot it. But I am having trouble figuring out how to read this data.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should try to use
[the `with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)
when opening files in Python. This is both more readable and removes the
possibility of a file being left unclosed (even when exceptions occur).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to be plotting it with matplotlib, probably the simplest thing to do is to use `numpy.loadtxt` [[docs]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), because you'll have numpy installed anyway:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> d = numpy.loadtxt("mdat.txt", skiprows=2)
>>> d
array([[ 0.   ,  0.021],
       [ 0.1  ,  0.021],
       [ 0.2  ,  0.021],
       [ 0.3  ,  0.021],
       [ 0.4  ,  0.021],
       [ 0.5  ,  0.021],
       [ 0.6  ,  0.021]])
```

Note that I had to add `skiprows=2` here to skip the header.  Then the times are `d[:,0]` and the charges `d[:,1]`, or you could get them explicitly with `loadtxt`:

```
>>> times, charges = numpy.loadtxt("mdat.txt", skiprows=2, unpack=True)
>>> times
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6])
>>> charges
array([ 0.021,  0.021,  0.021,  0.021,  0.021,  0.021,  0.021])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('data2.txt') as f:
    f=[x.strip() for x in f if x.strip()]
    data=[tuple(map(float,x.split())) for x in f[2:]]
    charges=[x[1] for x in data]
    times=[x[0] for x in data]
    print('times',times)
    print('charges',charges)
```

now charges and times contain:

```
times [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
charges [0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021]
```